# How to render ejs files in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs

As part of a MOOC I created a CRUD application using Node JS, Javascript, Express, MongoDB, and EJS.
Now, I want to convert it to a decentralized DAPP using Ethereum Solidity and Truffle Boxes aka boilerplate (at https://truffleframework.com/boxes).
I am using Truffle Webpack boilerplate for this conversion inside which I plan to re-use the existing code and connect it with Solidity Code but the only challenge I have is in using my EJS files with webpack.
I am unable to identify what changes shall I make in the Webpack config.js so that it renders the EJS files.

Please help if someone has tried to implement EJS files in Webpack.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways to accomplish, but I ended up using `WebpackShellPlugin` and `ejs-cli` to compile `.ejs` views:

```
new WebpackShellPlugin({
  onBuildEnd: [`${PATHS.node_modules}/ejs-cli/bin/ejs-cli --base-dir ${PATHS.root}/views/ '*.ejs' --out ${isDev ? PATHS.dev : PATHS.build}/`],
  safe: true
})
```

You will need to adjust above `webpack.config.js` block for your project specifics, but hopefully this will help in some way.

**ejs-cli**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-cli

**webpack-shell-plugin**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin